# Render html elements in email

Tags: html, email, html-email

I'm trying to render html in an email and even after searching the web, I am still a little confused.. Basically I would like to have say a box(div) with a background color display in the email. I'm sending the email using the php mail() function and trying to set the message body to a string such as: `"<div style='background:black;'>Test</div>"`, but instead of rendering the html, the email just displays the html text.. 
Is there an easy way of **rendering** the html? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sending the email as html or rich text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to properly encode your email to indicate that it is HTML by setting the Content-type to text/html.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME for solid background information.

Depending on your platform, there's almost certainly a toolset to simplify this.  For example, on Microsoft ASP.Net, I use [MvcMailer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek2MvcMailerSendsMailsWithASPNETMVCRazorViewsAndScaffolding.aspx).  If you specify your platform, I'll make a concrete recommendation.

For PHP, here's a great article on [sending nicely formatted HTML email](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)

```
$to = 'bob@example.com';

$subject = 'Website Change Reqest';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this in the header:

$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

This URL shows how to do this:

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=416467

(I am sure you already know this - You also have to make sure your client
can display HTML email)

Answer (score 1):

The first place you should look is the php docs.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3146

They provide an example on how to send html emails using the mail() function.

You may also want to read up on the best practices for sending html emails because each email client will render html differently.  CSS Support is very minimal and I do not recommend using divs either.  You really only want to use the most basic html tags like `<p>, <a>, <table> and <img />` tags.  All of your css should be inline as well.

Here is a great reference for css support.
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

If you are planning on sending large volumes of emails then you may want to look into a service for this such as http://mailchimp.com because the mail function isn't really meant for handling large volumes of emails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the headers before you can send HTML in emails using `mail();`

**For example:**

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <email@email.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Obviously you'll need to be careful how you use your new found HTML email powers as not all email clients will render it the same (you think cross testing browsers is a pain). There is a good guide here -> http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

There is also a fantastic website here that not only looks awesome but gives you all the information you'll need regarding what will work in what -> http://www.emailology.org/